# MVC cannot get the value from code to html page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

I am trying to get the value from the C# to MVC textbox. But its not displaying in HTML.

I used the following code:

```
foreach (CompilerError CompErr in results.Errors)
            {

                userProgram.CompileOutput = "Line number " + CompErr.Line +
                             ", Error Number: " + CompErr.ErrorNumber +
                             ", '" + CompErr.ErrorText + ";" +
                             Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine;
                output = userProgram.CompileOutput;
            }

var model = new UserProgram()
        {
            CompileOutput = output
        };
        return View(model);
```

The following code is in cshtml:

```
@Html.EditorFor(up => up.CompileOutput, new{style = "width:100px; height:50px; "})
```

Comment: Show your code to display it in view

Comment: @x2. - I have edited my question. Please look at that..

Comment: In HTML page, Its not displaying its remains same what we have have given as input.

Comment: What is the type of CompileOutput in UserProgram class?

Comment: @AbhinavRajan - virtual string

Comment: Any error you are getting?what is rendered in the markup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you post model to controller, and then change model in controller, in view it will display what you posted first, posted data has higher priority. You can try to clear modelstate

```
ModelState.Clear();
```

Comment: Thank u so much x2. We have been working it for about 14 hours. Thank u so so much. +1 for u....